# If statement to split date/time into periods

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
date_time={'Date_Fields':[datetime.date(2014,5,1),datetime.date(2015,5,1),datetime.date(2016,5,1),datetime.date(2018,5,1)]}
date_time=pd.DataFrame(date_time)
date_time["Analysis Period"]=""
```

Just a little back story, I need to create an Ameneded column called "Analysis Period" that splits the 36 month periods into 3 intervals. For example, (May 2014- April 2015),( May 2015- April 2016), and (May 2016- April 2017). This is to be used with our local tool.

I was able to accomplis this feat with the below code, however I wanted to know if there was a more effective way to do this without having to manually update the date ranges. 
Also in regards to the if statement below, originally I was trying to do one if statement with two corresponding elif statements. However, that didnt seem to workout. Could someone explain the reasoning as to why?

Thank you

```
if ((date_time["Date_Fields"]>= datetime.date(2014,5,1)) & (date_time["Date_Fields"]<=datetime.date(2015,4,30))) is not False:
date_time["Analysis Period"]=np.where(((date_time["Date_Fields"]>= datetime.date(2014,5,1)) & (date_time["Date_Fields"]<=datetime.date(2015,4,30))),'May 2014 to April 2015', date_time["Analysis Period"])

if ((date_time["Date_Fields"]>= datetime.date(2015,5,1)) & (date_time["Date_Fields"]<=datetime.date(2016,4,30))) is not False:
date_time["Analysis Period"]=np.where(((date_time["Date_Fields"]>= datetime.date(2015,5,1)) & (date_time["Date_Fields"]<=datetime.date(2016,4,30))),'May 2015 to April 2016', date_time["Analysis Period"])

if ((date_time["Date_Fields"]>= datetime.date(2016,5,1)) & (date_time["Date_Fields"]<=datetime.date(2017,4,30))) is not False:
date_time["Analysis Period"]=np.where(((date_time["Date_Fields"]>= datetime.date(2016,5,1)) & (date_time["Date_Fields"]<=datetime.date(2017,4,30))),'May 2016 to April 2017',date_time["Analysis Period"])
```

Comment: You need `pd.cut()`.

Comment: Thank you, will read into it.

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**
Consider the dataframe `date_time`

```
date_time = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Date_Fields=pd.date_range('2014-05-01', periods=12, freq='Q'),
    Other_Field=np.arange(12)
))

   Date_Fields  Other_Field
0   2014-06-30            0
1   2014-09-30            1
2   2014-12-31            2
3   2015-03-31            3
4   2015-06-30            4
5   2015-09-30            5
6   2015-12-31            6
7   2016-03-31            7
8   2016-06-30            8
9   2016-09-30            9
10  2016-12-31           10
11  2017-03-31           11
```

---

**Solution**
Use `pd.Series.dt.to_period` with `freq='A-Apr` to specify annual periods that end in April.

```
date_time.assign(**{
    'Analysis Period': date_time.Date_Fields.dt.to_period('A-Apr')
})

   Date_Fields  Other_Field Analysis Period
0   2014-06-30            0            2015
1   2014-09-30            1            2015
2   2014-12-31            2            2015
3   2015-03-31            3            2015
4   2015-06-30            4            2016
5   2015-09-30            5            2016
6   2015-12-31            6            2016
7   2016-03-31            7            2016
8   2016-06-30            8            2017
9   2016-09-30            9            2017
10  2016-12-31           10            2017
11  2017-03-31           11            2017
```

Comment: Great solution!